# How to test the re-rendering triggered by setState() in componentDidMount() in React 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that trigger re-rendering when I call `setState()` in `componentDidMount()`. Here is sample code:

```
import React from 'react'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      message: 'Hello'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchMessage().then((message) => {
      this.setState({ message })
    })
  }

  fetchMessage() {
    return Promise.resolve('World')
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.message
  }
}
```

and my test is like this:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'

describe('<MyComponent>', () => {
  it('renders World', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />)
    expect(wrapper.text()).toEqual('World') # => results shows Hello
  })
})
```

Please note, I am using `enzyme` to assist with my test.

The test failed because the returned results is `Hello` which is the initial rendering.

So my question here is what's the way to ensure that the re-rendering has triggered before carrying out the assertion?

Comment: You need to use `mount` and not `shallow`

Answer (score 0):

Hellow,

You have to use [`mount`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html) if you want to test lifeCycleMethod.

Note that setState is async, so if this.fetchMessage take time, you will find yourself into a beautiful race condition on your render and in your test.

To avoid this, try to extract the render into a stateless function.